# Density of subspaces of $L^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Let $D$ be a bounded domain of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with smooth boundary $\partial D$. How can check if the following spaces are dense (or not) in $L^2(D)$.

$$D_1:=\{f\in H^3(D): f\rvert_{\partial D}=(\Delta f)\rvert_{\partial D}=0\}.$$
$$D_2:=\{f\in H^3(D): (\Delta f)\rvert_{\partial D}=0\}.$$
I think $D_1$ is dense while $D_2$ is not. I tried to use density of test functions but I don't get the final result.

Thank you for any suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set of smooth functions with compact support $C_c^\infty(D)$ is a subset of both $D_1$ and $D_2$ and it is dense in $L^2(D)$. Hence, $D_1$ and $D_2$ are dense in $L^2(D)$ as well.

Comment: Thank you. I have some related questions: 1. how the laplacian of compactly supported function is compactly supported. 2. Can we conclude from the previous result that $\{(f,f\rvert_{\partial D}) : f\in C^\infty(\overline{D}), (\Delta f)\rvert_{\partial D}=0\}$ is dense in $L^2(D)\times L^2(\partial D)$. Thanks again.

Comment: 1) the complement of the support of $u\in C_c^\infty(D)$ is open, on this set $u=0$, hence all derivatives are zero, hence the support of all derivatives of $u$ is contained in the support of $u$.

Comment: Thank you. What do you think about 2)?

Comment: Misread. This is entire different question. Please post  it as a new question.